# ASP.NET - HTML Form in JQuery Dialog not working on the aspx-page but working in the html page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, forms, visual-studio-2010

I am using the JQuery Modal dialog to display a small form and it works perfectly on an html page (in Visual Studio 2010). However when I create the same form in an aspx page the form submission doesn't work as expected. Even the simplest of things such as html5 input fields being required, doesn't produce the error message when left empty. I feel something on the aspx page is interfering with it. I believe there is some kind of an error with the form tag in my asps page and the asp:content - 'HeadContent' being a default form itself... can anyone help me solve this problem?

This is how my html form looks like:-

https://plnkr.co/edit/uUWZc9PNSABQ9mpcwti9?p=preview

The same thing produced on an aspx page:-

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckInSystem.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/jscript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ProgramFiles/Popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <button id="create-user" type="button">Please Check-in</button>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="New Visitor Check-in">
     <form id="myForm" action="About.aspx" method="post">
      <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>
      <div class="formContainer">
        <div class="row">
          <b>Visitor:</b>
          <input id="visitor" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 60px" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <b>Type of Visit:</b>
          <asp:dropdownlist id="TypeOfVisitDesc" runat="server" datavaluefield="TypeOfVisitKey" datatextfield="TypeOfVisitDesc" cssclass="ddlist" datasourceid="TypeOfVisitDataSrc"></asp:dropdownlist>
          <asp:linqdatasource id="TypeOfVisitDataSrc" runat="server" contexttypename="CheckInSystem.CheckInSystemDataContext" entitytypename="" tablename="TypeOfVisits"></asp:linqdatasource>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <b>Visitee:</b>
          <input id="visitee" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 59px" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <b>Arrival:</b>
          <input id="arrival" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 59px" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <b>Departure:</b>
          <input id="departure" type="text" runat="server" style="margin-left: 33px" required="true" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" runat="server" value="Check-In" class="myButton" onclick="return true;" />
      </div>

     </form>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I have purposefully not inserted any code behind.. because all I want is the 'required' fields to show an error when left empty... even that doesnt work.

I believe there is some kind of an error with the form tag in my asps page and the asp:content - 'HeadContent' being a default form itself... can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`required=true` requires a `<form>` element to apply the validation.

ASP.NET Forms removes all `<form>` tag from the page to replace them with a custom `<form>` element that is specific to ASP.NET Forms.

This is why the standard validation is not working under ASP.NET Forms. Take a look at the html code produced by ASP.NET using your browser > View Source feature.